JDBC TLS Connection error from an Oracle Linux 8 to a SQL server 2016
The attempt to establish the connection failed.
Below is the Python script code, which failed with the error "the driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption". I got the same error for the jdbc_url is configured as "encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true".
jdbc_url = "jdbc:sqlserver://mysqlserver:1433;databaseName=mysqldb;encrypt=false"
cnn=jaydebeapi.connect(jdbc_driver, jdbc_url, [db_user, db_pass], jdbc_jar_path)

I tried openssl as below on the linux node and got the output "no peer certificate available" and "No client certificate CA names sent".
openssl s_client -connect mysqlserver:1433 -debug

The Windows registry confirmed TLS 1.2 is enabled.
The Windows event log of the sql server showed the error related to the Python script execution - "a TLS 1.2 connection request was received from a remote client application, but none of the cipher suites supported by the client application was supported by the server. The SSL connection request has failed." I checked "SSL Cipher Suite Order" on this Windows 2012 server. SSL Cipher Suite order is not configured. AES256-SHA256 and AES128-SHA256 are in Windows 2012 default cipher suites. On the Linux side, I confirmed both cipher suites are active via openssl.
The Windows event log showed nothing related to the attempted connections from openssql.
This SQL Server uses a self-signed certificate. I have no issue connecting to this SQL server from a Windows workstation using SSMS.
What should I do next? Thank you.

Do a Wireshark trace and compare Client Hello and Server Hello, you will probably find a cipher mismatch. Why are you using an out of date and unsupported version of Windows Server anyway?

openssl s_client doesn't work against SQL Servers because MS-TDS establishes encrypted connections at a later point in the session (similar to STARTTLS on SMTP).

It doesn't matter which ciphersuites your Linux machine has, JDBC is using JVM which uses its own ciphersuites. JVM is configurable using -D commandline arguments which you could probably manage from Python via jpype.startJVM().

The connection worked after I switched to a SQL Server 2016 running on a Windows 2019 server. It is my bad to pick a server without checking the OS. Thanks for all the comments pointing me in the right direction, especially the one from @Charlieface.
